# Submitting a form with jQuery for Google reCaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have the following code.

When a form is submitted I wan't the reCaptcha to execute and the form to submit if the score is greater than 0.8. I don't get any errors in the console and the form does not submit no matter what I try. But it does get to

```
console.log("Success ! Submitting data");
```

so I know the code is working up until that point.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=KEYXXX"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        $( "#EnquiryForm" ).submit(function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var $this = $(this);
          grecaptcha.execute('KEYXXX', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {

             fetch('https://SOMEDOMAIN.com/process.php?&recaptcha_response='+token).then(function(response) {
                 response.json().then(function(data) {
                    if (data.success && (data.score > 0.8)) {
                        console.log("Success ! Submitting data");

                        // HOW DO I SUBMIT THE FORM HERE ?
                        // I HAVE TRIED THE FOLLOWING 

                        // $this.submit();
                        // $this.unbind('submit').submit();
                        // $( "#EnquiryForm" ).submit();
                        // $(e.target).submit();
                    }
                  }).catch(function(){
                     console.log("Captcha error, no response");
                  });
              });

          });
    });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please presume the backend script is working properly as I am sure it is.

I have just tried `e.target.submit()` and now get an error message: 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.target.submit is not a function`

If thats helps anyone

Comment: Im not sure you can chain response.json() with a .then(). You should close the first .then() before you start a new one/

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to submit the form using `form.submit()` - the native DOM method, not the jQuery method.

So instead of `$(e.target).submit();`, try `e.target.submit();`.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.target.submit is not a function

Comment: Weird. Try `$this[0].submit()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making two different ajax calls you should do it all at once. By submitting the captcha token separately you are still leaving the endpoint that submits the form unsecured.

```
$(function() {
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    $("#EnquiryForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      grecaptcha.execute('KEYXXX', {
        action: 'contact'
      }).then(function(token) {

        var url = new URL('https://SOMEDOMAIN.com/process.php');

        var params = {
            recaptcha_response: token,

            // sample parameters
            name: $("#name").val(),
            date: $("#date").val()
        };

        Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))

        fetch(url).then(function(response) {
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            if (data.success && (data.score > 0.8)) {
              console.log("Success ! Submitting data");
              // $this.submit();
              // $this.unbind('submit').submit();
              // $( "#EnquiryForm" ).submit();
              // $(e.target).submit();
            }
          }).catch(function() {
            console.log("Captcha error, no response");
          });
        });

      });
    });
  });
});
```

Or, if you're not submitting via ajax then you should put that token in a hidden form input and process it along with the form. By checking the captcha separately you are allowing attackers to completely skip the captcha which entirely defeats the purpose of the captcha.

Comment: I do get this, but for legacy reasons I can't change this. Would you be able to help me with the question ?

Comment: you might as well just remove the captcha then. "legacy reasons" is used as an excuse to do things wrong far too often. however, if you insist on doing it wrong, and you understand that you're doing it wrong and completely wasting your time, then you need to do all this on the submit button's click event instead of the form's submit event. it needs to be that way because you are using `preventDefault` on the form's submit handler.

Comment: Honestly I do appreciate what you are saying. Thank you.